# use Python urllib.urlopen to send data accurately

Tags: python

I want to use Python to simulate a login action which acquires some message sending via HTTP GET method. So I write something like this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

urlopen(Request(URL, data=data_for_verify.encode(), method='GET'))
```

The problem is, it doesn't do the same as a real login action which like this (scratch from Wireshark, HTTP printable data only)

```
GET /rjsdcctrl?mac%3dfcaa14ec56f3%26ipv4%3d1681312010%26ipv61%3d0%26ipv62%3d0%26ipv63%3d0%26ipv64%3d0%26product%3d33554432%26mainver%3d67108864%26subver%3d1610612736 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: HttpCall
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: 10.0.6.251
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And what my program did is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 10.0.6.251:80
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.4
Connection: close
Content-Length: 161
rjsdcctrl?mac%3dfcaa14ec56f3%26ipv4%3d1681312010%26ipv61%3d0%26ipv62%3d0%26ipv63%3d0%26ipv64%3d0%26product%3d33554432%26mainver%3d67108864%26subver%3d1610612736
```

A real login action have the header comes first, and do not have the line `GET / HTTP /1.1`

or it just a header without content, and the first line GET contain the real request message. How can I simulate that using Python's urllib?
I use Python 3.4

Comment: I would recomend the use of Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/) for tasks like this

Comment: As @Daniel states for a GET request you should add the parameters to the url. Using the `data` argument would actually send the data in the request body. Also to use `headers` you can use the keyword argument headers e.g. `urlopen(url, headers=my_headers)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend @Daniel's answer, you can make use of `urllib.urlencode` method to prepare your get parameter string and also `headers` keyword argument to override default headers. So for example:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.example.com/'
data = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3'
}
headers = {
    'Overriden-Header': 'Overriden Header Value'
}

## Update the url and make the actual requests
url = '%s?%s' % (url, urllib.urlencode(data))
response = urllib.urlopen(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Result comes like this `GET /?b'rjsdcctrl?mac%3dfcaa14ec56f3%26ipv4%3d1681312010%26ipv61%3d0%26ipv62%3d0%26i‌​pv63%3d0%26ipv64%3d0%26product%3d33554432%26mainver%3d67108864%26subver%3d1610612‌​736 ' HTTP/1.1` It have a `?b` at the beginning and surrounded by quote mark

Comment: That is because of your `data_to_verify.encode()` methods result. Make sure the data you pass to `urlencode` method is a python dictionary and is not already encoded. See how I have passed data to `urllib.urlencode` method in the example above.

Comment: Can you update your question with what `data_for_verify.encode()` method returns ?

Comment: Thank you! It is wrong using a raw string to encode, I use a dict instead and I got a proper response. By the way, `urllib.urlencode` method actually replace by `urllib.parse.urlencode` in Python 3.4 :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `data` parameter if you don't want to send data as part of the body. Append the value to the URL:

```
full_url = "%s?%s" % (URL, data_for_verify.encode())
urlopen(full_url)
```

Comment: I have tried your code. It comes like this `GET /?b'rjsdcctrl?mac%3dfcaa14ec56f3%26ipv4%3d1681312010%26ipv61%3d0%26ipv62%3d0%26ipv63%3d0%26ipv64%3d0%26product%3d33554432%26mainver%3d67108864%26subver%3d1610612736 ' HTTP/1.1` It have a `?b` at the beginning and surrounded by quote mark

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing to get that. Are you passing the whole `urlopen` call somewhere? Please show your full code.